# How to change base url when installing webdriverio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, webdriver, webdriver-io

Can you help please? I want to change base url when install webdriverio, but I can't edit the default: "(http://localhost)". Maybe I should press something? Also I don't get that why I chose reporter - allure, but I anyway have - spec?

My Actual Result:

Which reporter do you want to use? spec

But Expected is:

Which reporter do you want to use? spec, allure

UPD: I didn't pressed "Space" button when I chose allure. It is an answer. But what about base url? How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

- When you have a list of options > You can select the option by UP and DOWN keys and then hit the ENTER key
- When there is no option and it's showing a default value like http://localhost > In this case you have manually to type the URL (You will not be able to edit http://localhost)
- When there is a Y/n option > You have to manually type Y or n for the selection (Without typing any value will keep it to default)
- When you have multiple options like reporter type > You can use the UP and DOWN key then hit the SPACEBAR key, and finally hit the ENTER key.

I hope this will help you.